# Docker compose VSTS task failder

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, azure-devops

I'working on Asp.Bet Core 2 app with MSSQL on Linux. I would like to configure CI and CD to Azure.
I defined docker-compose task in Visual Studio Team Services, but I'm getting an error.

```
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4725450Z ##[section]Starting: Create images
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4801610Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4817660Z Task         : Docker Compose
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4835680Z Description  : Build, push or run multi-container Docker applications. Task can be used with Docker or Azure Container registry.
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4852370Z Version      : 0.4.7
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4867100Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4881820Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848006)
2017-11-09T20:24:09.4897520Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-09T20:24:10.5040990Z [command]/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /opt/vsts/work/1/s/docker-compose.yml -f /opt/vsts/work/1/s/docker-compose.ci.build.yml -f /home/vsts/agent/.docker-compose.1510259050468.yml -p Travelingowe build
2017-11-09T20:24:10.8628630Z db uses an image, skipping
2017-11-09T20:24:10.8646610Z Building api
2017-11-09T20:24:10.9373040Z Step 1/7 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
2017-11-09T20:24:12.0041790Z 2.0: Pulling from microsoft/aspnetcore
2017-11-09T20:25:03.6328690Z Digest: sha256:e36cb8d1edcd1bfd7aea0412349482a9c1a601089d76d1a294067f5f7f1098a9
2017-11-09T20:25:03.6497680Z Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
2017-11-09T20:25:03.6524910Z  ---> e0e49def2506
2017-11-09T20:25:03.6551560Z Step 2/7 : MAINTAINER Maciej Skuratowski <maciejskuratowski@gmail.com>
2017-11-09T20:25:03.7496070Z  ---> Running in e7667861d293
2017-11-09T20:25:03.9222120Z  ---> 24ba03484562
2017-11-09T20:25:03.9436840Z Removing intermediate container e7667861d293
2017-11-09T20:25:03.9458600Z Step 3/7 : ARG source
2017-11-09T20:25:04.0562980Z  ---> Running in 7b57f9fc515f
2017-11-09T20:25:04.2292420Z  ---> 4d07188edf18
2017-11-09T20:25:04.2503550Z Removing intermediate container 7b57f9fc515f
2017-11-09T20:25:04.2581270Z Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /app
2017-11-09T20:25:04.5347440Z  ---> 4546b8dc771f
2017-11-09T20:25:04.5527690Z Removing intermediate container 0a595d10e668
2017-11-09T20:25:04.5558170Z Step 5/7 : EXPOSE 80
2017-11-09T20:25:04.6765650Z  ---> Running in aa273cc9ca2c
2017-11-09T20:25:04.8330020Z  ---> 6dd874db617e
2017-11-09T20:25:04.8619290Z Removing intermediate container aa273cc9ca2c
2017-11-09T20:25:04.8650100Z Step 6/7 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
2017-11-09T20:25:04.8686070Z Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder211771018/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
2017-11-09T20:25:04.9064960Z ##[error]db uses an image, skipping
2017-11-09T20:25:04.9127660Z ##[error]Building api
2017-11-09T20:25:04.9175860Z ##[error]Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder211771018/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
2017-11-09T20:25:04.9258880Z ##[error]/usr/local/bin/docker-compose failed with return code: 1
2017-11-09T20:25:04.9325830Z ##[section]Finishing: Create images
```

Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    image: api
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "testtest3030!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8001:1433"
```

and docker-compose.ci.build.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

      ci-build:
        image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-1.1
        volumes:
          - .:/src
        working_dir: /src
        command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln && dotnet publish ./Travelingowe.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

Also I attached my VSTS docker-compose taks:
[image]

Do you have any idea for I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems that you pass `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder211771018/obj/Docker/publish` as argument, and this path doesn't exist. did you check that it's valid?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution? (Updated the answer with detail steps to deploy to azure)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I faced the same issue a few days ago. Your issue is inside your DockerFile. For example, let's look at my file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY  ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","MyWeb.Api.dll" ]
```

If docker cannot find the path that you specify in your COPY command, it will produce an error:

```
Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder211771018/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
```

So, basically, what you need to do is to fix your build release path (you need to be sure that files after the build in the right folder).

Also, there is a problem, if you execute:

> docker-compose build

It doesn't build the solution. That is why DockerFile cannot find the needed folder. If you execute the following command before your docker-compose, it will work.

```
dotnet publish ./YourSolution.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error, the reason is that there isn’t the obj/Docker/publish folder or file. (check the answer of Leonid)

The `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` file is for building the project and the `docker-compose.yml` file is used for running the project, so you need to build the project through `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` file with Dokcer-compose task, then build/run image with `docker-compose.yml` file with Docker-compose task.

There is a thread about docker-compose.ci.build.yml, docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile: [Asp.net core with linux docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278497/asp-net-core-with-linux-docker-container)

Update:

Refer to these steps to deploy project to Azure:

1. Create a new build definition
2. Add Docker Compose task (Docker Compose File: `**/docker-compose.ci.build.yml`; Action: `Run a Docker Compose command`; Command:`run ci-build`)
3. Add Copy Files task (Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[your project path]/obj/Docker/publish`; Contents: `**`; Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`)
4. Add Publish Build Artifacts task (Path to publish: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`)
5. Create a new release definitioin
6. Add Azure App Service Deploy task (Package or folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[artifact build definition name]/[artifact name]`; Uncheck `Publish using Web Deploy option`)