# Asp.net core with linux docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

For a asp.net core project template in VS 2017, there are docker-compose.ci.build.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./WebAppCoreDockerTest.sln && dotnet publish ./WebAppCoreDockerTest.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webappcoredockertest:
    image: webappcoredockertest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    build:
      context: ./WebAppCoreDockerTest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
RUN echo "Oh dang look at that $source"
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAppCoreDockerTest.dll"]
```

The Dockerfile uses the files in obj/Docker/publish (copied to container) if source argument is null and docker-compose.ci.build.yml puhlishs project to obj/Docker/publish, I assume they are related.

So the question is **How to use them together**? (docker-compose.ci.build.yml publishes files to obj/Docker/publish and Dockerfile use published files)

Comment: Be careful with command:
command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./WebAppCoreDockerTest.sln && dotnet publish ./WebAppCoreDockerTest.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"

The current command will add test libraries into your docker image. I suggest excluding test projects from the build.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks, a question: the context of docker-compose.ci.build.yml command is in local or in container and copy files from /src/WebAppCoreDockerTest/obj/Docker/publish/ to local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` file is for building the project, as you mentioned.  It uses the `aspnetcore-build` base image which is much heftier than the `aspnetcore` image used by the Dockerfile.  The `Dockerfile` gets used by the `build` section of the docker-compose.yml file.

Everything works together with these two steps:

1. `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml run ci-build`
2. `docker-compose up --build`

The `-f` option in the first command allows you to specify a compose file other than the default `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, a question: the context of docker-compose.ci.build.yml command is in local or in container and copy files from /src/WebAppCoreDockerTest/obj/Docker/publish/ to local?

Comment: It is local context.

Comment: @Leonid If I change working_dir (working_dir:/src2), then it can't find the project, so it looks for project in src folder, but there isn't src folder in local, what's happen?

Comment: @Leonid Seems the context is in container. I add additional volumn (./result:/src/WebAppCoreDockerTest/obj/Docker/publish), then the published files will be copied from container to result folder in local.